# Bus error (core dumped) Nautilus not working

Tags: linux, fedora, php, gnome

I was downloading php docs from Firefox and suddenly it hung and I had to kill it and after that to see if anything downloaded or not.

I started Nautilus but it didn't open and when I looked into the error it says:

Bus error (core dumped)

And now no file manager is starting.

I am kinda frustrated now and really looking for some help, I would be really grateful for any help.

**OS:** Linux fedora